# how to avoid two socket with same port number python

Tags: python, sockets

Now here is sample for the server part of socket.
I want to have serverSocket and connectionSocket with different port number, but for now, they are using same port number.

```
from socket import *
serverPort = 12000
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
serverSocket.bind((‘’,serverPort))
serverSocket.listen(1)
print (‘The server is ready to receive’)
while 1:
 connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()

 sentence = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
 capitalizedSentence = sentence.upper()
 connectionSocket.send(capitalizedSentence)
 connectionSocket.close()
```

if they are using same port number, would there be some collision?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing to avoid, and there is really no easy way to avoid it - this is how TCP is supposed to work.

In TCP there are 2 kinds of sockets:

- listening server sockets
- connected sockets

The server sockets start listening to incoming connections with `listen`; and wait for client connections with `accept`. Clients create a socket that is connected to the server address `(host, port)`. When the server `accept`s a connection, a **new** connected socket is created between the `(client_address, client_port)` and `(server_address, server_port)`. The TCP stack on the server can see from **status bits** easily if the packet is a connection request, or destined to an already connected socket. If it is a communication between already connected sockets, then it finds out the file descriptor that is bound on the local address and local port **and** is connected with the source address, source port of the remote end.

The connected socket will have the same port as the listening server socket; both Ende of the socket know 4 things: *local address*, *local port*, *remote address* and *remote port*. You can have 1 server socket bound on `10.20.30.40:12345` at the same time with thousands of sockets connected from `10.20.30.40:12345` to thousands distinct addresses.

There is really congestion only in the connection attempt phase; the `server_socket.listen(1)` means that the server will queue just 1 incoming connection; subsequent connections will be rejected until the incoming connection is accepted.

From Linux manual pages, `listen(2)` on the `backlog` argument of `sock.listen`:

> The backlog argument defines the maximum length  to  which  the
>   queue of pending connections for sockfd may grow.  If a connection request arrives when the queue is  full,  the  client  may
>   receive  an error with an indication of `ECONNREFUSED` or, if the
>   underlying protocol supports retransmission, the request may be
>   ignored so that a later reattempt at connection succeeds.

Comment: if there are lots of clients, would there be congestion for the same port?

Comment: Only in the connect phase.

Comment: but if there are many sockets listning same port, when a message came, where should message go?  it is going to be tough.

Answer (score 0):

Althouh I've never used raw sockets in Python, I guess this question more generally deals with how TCP and IP work.

When a server listens for connections on a port, clients will connect to *that* port, and the TCP connection can be identified by the quadruple *(server_addr, server_port, client_addr, client_port)*, so there is no ambiguity when packets belonging to different connections will be sent or recieved, because the *(client_addr, client_port)* part will be different for each of them.

That said, there is no conflict in the addressing.

However, note that it is common that servers fork (or spawn a thread) after accepting each request, so that the main proces (or thread) can keep acceprint connections while other connections are handled by the forked processes (or threads). In your case, instead, once your server starts processing a request, it computes the response before calling `accept()` again, so any other client will have to wait before having its request served.

Comment: even if I do fork, but they all use same port, I am afraid there will be conjestion.

Comment: @SihanWang that only depends on the resources the server has at its disposal. If, say, you are running on a 8-cores machine with enough memory and running on a loopback interface, it would take you some effort to seriously overload it (unless it is already). I'm not sure it is a good idea to limit the incoming queue to 1, but if the server thread only does the accept/fork loop it can accept *a lot* of connections. Of course, if responses are expensive to compute and requests are many, at some point you will overload your CPU/memory/network interface.